# Query Syntax Error for UPDATE with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, pdo

Hey i have an update query with an inner join but i cannot get the syntax correct to make it work... this is what i currently have:

```
UPDATE t1 
   SET t1.quantity = t1.quantity - ?  FROM items t1
INNER JOIN users t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
   WHERE t1.item_id=? AND t2.uid= ?
```

The syntax error says its near here:

```
near 'FROM items t1 INNER JOIN users t2 ON t1.id=
```

I'm using `pdo` encase you wondered why i have question marks!

Hope you can help!

Comment: it all matches my database as far as syntax goes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following query, the syntax you have is valid in SQL Server but not in MySQL

```
UPDATE items t1
INNER JOIN users t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
SET t1.quantity = t1.quantity - ?  
WHERE t1.item_id=? AND t2.uid= ?
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecc4a)

Comment: Finally. I saw many wrong answers with too many upvotes here on SO for some reason...